# SBS 2011, updates begin to install, then stop after a few seconds

Tags: windows-sbs-2011

On SBS 2011 SP1, I am trying to install updates from Microsoft Update. I leave all the updates selected, then click Install Updates. The progress bar goes for maybe 5 or 6 seconds, then stops and the previous screen is displayed ("Install Updates"). I have installed updates on this server before with no issues. I didn't see anything in Event Viewer that might help. Any ideas what is causing the updates not to install?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. I tried running `dism /online /cleanup-image /restorehealth` at someone's suggestion. The `/restorehealth` option is not compatible with Windows Server 2008. This got me on the right path, however.
2. I tried running `Windows Update Trouble Shooter`. It fixed three out of four issues that it is apparently capable of fixing, but not the Windows Update problem.
3. I tried running `sfc /scannow`. Then, I tried running Windows Update again. This time, it was as if I was running it for the first time. Let me clarify. The last several attempts at running it, it knew that there were X number of updates to install. This time, it didn't know of any right off the bat, so I had to tell it to `Check for Windows Updates`. This was promising. However, it came back with an error. On this fresh run, it didn't allow me to `Check for Microsoft Updates`. However, after the error after running `Check for Windows Updates`, the option to `Check for Microsoft Updates` became available. I ran it, expecting the same error that I got when running `Check for Windows Updates`, putting me back where I had been. However, running `Check for Microsoft Updates` worked. Perhaps running `Check for Windows Updates` a second time would have worked, too. I don't know. Anyway, as I type this, updates are installing. The problem seems to have been fixed by running `sfc /scannow`.